# On a characterisation of strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

The question is the following

> Let $E$ be a Banach Space, prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges strongly to
>   $x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ there is a dense subset $S$ of the unit ball $B_{E^*}$
>   where the application $ f \mapsto f(x_n)$ converges uniformly to 
>   $f \mapsto f(x)$.

The $\Rightarrow$ implication was easy, the $\Leftarrow$ is a bit more tricky, well, I believe is not that much more difficult, I just need to prove that $x_n$ is bounded and I can complete the proof, but I did not manage to find an good argument for that.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: The fact that the convergence is _uniform_ is crucial. That says $\lim_n\sup_{f\in S}|f(x_n)-f(x)|=0$. Note that $f(x_n)-f(x)=f(x_n-x)$. Now $\sup_{f\in S}|f(x_n-x)|$ is _what_, exactly?

Comment: I think I understand you, my only problem when comparing $ \sup_{f \in S}|f(x_n−x)|$ with $\sup_{f \in B_{E^*}}|f(x_n−x)|$ I feel like I need a bound for $||x_n - x||$ which was not assumed. Is this bound necessary and in that case, how could I prove it?

Comment: I don't know what bound you think you need. You just have to show that this sup equals that sup for one fixed vector $x_n-x$. That vector being an element of $E$ is the only "bound" you need here

Comment: That is completely true! Thank you very much!